# C# ObjectDisposedException caused by Snackbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

I am working with MaterialDesign Xaml Toolkit for WPF/C#, and I want to add Snackbars (A message bar that popups from under) to my application. It has a button and its called an action, not like the delegate `Action`, lets for simplicity in this context call it `btn_A3`. When a task is completed or an error is caught the popup displays the message, and when `btn_A3` is clicked on the event of an `Exception` it would show the `Exception` Stack Trace in a `MessageBox`, I have thankfully somehow with trail and error managed to accomplish that, as the source on the internet at scarce and confusing

but it throws `System.ObjectDisposedException : 'Safe handle has been closed'` when i close the `MessageBox`

This is my code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        try{
            int x = 0;
            x = int.Parse(smpl.Text);
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());}

        catch (Exception ex) {           
            List<String> santa= new List<String>();
            santa.Add(ex.Message);
            foreach (var s in santa){
                snackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue(s,"SHOW ERROR", x => MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace), s);}}}
```

---

```
public void Enqueue<TArgument>(object content, object? actionContent, Action<TArgument?>? actionHandler, TArgument? actionArgument);
```

Comment: Typo: `MessageBox.Show(x.StackTrace)`.

Comment: @aepot no that ain't it, ex is the name of the exception, that lambda expression works for some reason

Comment: Because `ex` is captured by lambda. I know that it doesn't solve anything but it's a typo.

Comment: @aepot I am not an expert in lambda expressions or delegates but I tried doing something like this  ....  `x => MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace + x)`  but it still threw the exception, all i got was to include the x after the ` =>` and it would be ok

Comment: @aepot I did not undestand what you mean in you second comment, Thank you for your patience

Comment: Ok. Remove list and foreach loop from `catch` and write simply `snackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue(ex.Message, "SHOW ERROR", x => MessageBox.Show(x.StackTrace), ex);`. This wouldn't help with `Disposed` but makes the code correct.

Comment: Let's try to fix `snackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue(ex.Message, "SHOW ERROR", x => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(x.StackTrace)), ex);`

Comment: The second last method worked but the disposed problem cannot be solved with that method as it says  CS1660 : Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type ....... @aepot

Comment: `snackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue(ex.Message, "SHOW ERROR", x => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => MessageBox.Show(x.StackTrace))), ex);`

Comment: Thank you I am really great full for that have been at this for two days, Thank you @aepot

Comment: @aepot Can you also post it as an answer so i can up vote it, really thank you again

Comment: I posted. Could you accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from the person above @aepot and thanks to him this get the job done thank you!, now you can click on the button inside to display your own messages

```
snackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue(ex.Message, "SHOW ERROR", x => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => MessageBox.Show(x.StackTrace))), ex);
```